# How to write variable number in range

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, range

Here is my code and I want to use the number from the .csv file to control how many numbers will be generated.

```
with open('number.csv','rb') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
num = [row['123'] for row in reader]
a = [randint(12, 20) for i in range(???)]
```

??? is the value in .csv file.so the question is how to write ???.

.csv is like(in my .csv only have one value. ['5']):

```
123  --row1:name
5    --row2:value
```

So there is only 1 value in the CSV file.

Comment: You have a *list of strings* (`num` will be `['5', '...', '...']`). Which one did you want to use to determine the number of times `randint()` is called for `a`?

Comment: in my .csv only have one value. ['5']

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add that? There is no need to use a list in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use a list comprehension to read just one row. Use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to get the only row you need.

Next, you'll have to convert the single value to an integer:

```
with open('number.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    row = next(reader)
count = int(row['123'])
a = [randint(12, 20) for i in range(count)]
```

Comment: error happened.self._fieldnames = self.reader.next()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. would you mind fix it?

Comment: @zhou: your `csvfile` object is already closed. You need to take care you put the `next()` call *in the `with` block* so the file is not yet closed.